# How to kill a disowned while loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting

So I've done something like this:

```
$ while true; do ssh sysremote -CN; done & disown %
```

In the `ps -ef` only `ssh sysremote -CN` is listed.

How do I kill the `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I figured it out.

You find the shell it spawned from, kill the shell, everything goes away